# Screen of notebook turned off when charger plugged in or out

Tags: windows-10, display, nvidia-graphics-card, refresh-rate

I am using Asus Tuf Dash F15 with Windows 10 64bit OS. The notebook has GeForce RTX 3050 Graphics Card.

When I plug the charger in or out the screen turned off for 3-4 seconds. Sometimes the screen never turns on.

Refresh rate of the screen changes from 60 (on battery) to 144 (when charging) Hz. Making some research people arguing the problem caused due to change in refresh rate of the screen. However, changing the refresh rate manually is not permanent solution and work only for first try. Then it starts change the rate again.

Windows, Asus and Nvidia updates are all up to date.

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Nvidia updates are all up to date.  .....   Also update BIOS and Chipset.

Comment: There is not any driver left to update :)

Comment: Probably now wait for a new Nvidia driver to fix the issue.

Comment: stabilizing the rate at 60 Hz may fix the problem. If anybody has solution is welcomed.